# Outputting to the Console in C# on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, console

We are trying to debug some web services code we're running in C# on IIS. I am new to Windows programming and have no idea how to view output to the console. We've got some write statements in the code, but I can't figure out how to view the console while this thing is running. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at ASP.NET tracing

here is a handy link to get you started: http://www.asp101.com/articles/robert/tracing/default.asp

you can enable application wide tracing if you place the following in your web.config, then you will have access to your trace.axd

```
<trace enabled="true" 
    localOnly="false" 
    pageOutput="false" 
    requestLimit="500" 
    traceMode="SortByTime"
/>
```

Comment: Wow - get the answer even after stealing the answer from someone else!

Answer (score 7):

I have found the Trace feature extremely helpful.  You can get there by going to:
http://mysiteurl/trace.axd

In your web.config, place the following within the System.Web tag:

```
<trace enabled="true" 
       localOnly="false" 
       pageOutput="false" 
       requestLimit="500" 
       traceMode="SortByTime"
/>
```

Now from your code behind, you can inject some logging by doing:

```
HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn("I Made It Here!");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using asp.net then trace.axd should contain trace statements (as long as its turned on).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to get a console for IIS. CLOSEST you will come is Debug.WriteLine w/ a debugger attached or using page tracing. Recommendation would be to use a logging framework that will write to debugger (when attached) as well as a file and possibly the event log (all configured via your listeners).

Some great ones are log4net and NLog.

Comment: Since .net comes with built in logging I always wonder why people still use other logging packages...

Comment: because tracing doesn't work when in a production environment. and w/ shared components, you don't want to be tied to web based logging if the same code will be used on the web as well as a windows app or service.

Comment: The Trace in System.Diagnostics doesn't work in production?  I'm pretty sure they do, as long as it's enabled.  Built in trace switches, trace sources, filters and listeners...

Comment: if you have <deployment retail="true" /> set in the config (which you should for production), then it disables it.