# Running executables on iis7

Tags: iis, process, background, executable

I'm trying to run an executable from inside iis7. The executable is a console application i created and i'm trying to run it with Process.Start().
The process runs on the background (i see it on the process list) but without the console window.

How can i make it run with the console window ?

I already tried the "allow desktop interaction" in the iis admin service options. Didn't work.

Comment: It sounds as though you are stroking the cat the wrong way, and complaining that it doesn't purr in satisfaction.

Comment: What does your console application do? It sounds like there must be a better way to achieve your actual objective.

Answer (score 0):

If what you *really* want to do is to trace the behavor of your web application, then attempting to write to a console window is NOT the right approach.

The answer is further elaborated here: [Outputting to the Console in C# on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762282/outputting-to-the-console-in-c-on-iis)

**EDIT:**

Maybe you should consider porting your console application logic to a `ServicedComponent` and register it with COM+. That will allow you some degrees of freedom with respect to the context in which the component logic is being executed.

Comment: I'm not trying to trace the behaviour of my web application. I'm trying to run a colsole application that runs things on the background when a request is sent to the server. I have to run it on another process b/c of several limitations. I can't just run my code in a separate dll.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what those limitations are, and let the responders help clarify if they can be mediated. IIS is not for spawning console applications. If the limitations you refer to relate to security and/or system privileges, then maybe the community can help you with proper solutions to those issues.

Comment: The fact that it's a console application and i have limitations is not important. Even if i try to execute "notepad.exe", the process starts but the actual notepad window doesn't show up.